# Edit read-only Account fields without a single line of apex or VF page code

Tags: custom-button, profile, account, fields, read-only

I have a custom User Profile that has read-only access to Account fields, but I would like to make a custom button on Account detail page, that allows these Users specifically edit address fields (Street, City, Postal Code etc.) bypassing these read-only field permissions using only configuration and not using Apex code or VF pages or URL hacking. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Only Trigger or APEX code can run on system mode and override the CRUD settings. To achieve this requirement you need some custom code not possible only through configuration.

Comment: There is a way to do it through configuration, I am sure, but only expert could tell me this.

Comment: @Pmal12 unless user has an Edit access to Account and fields, that user will not able to edit those fields through Configuration. Only option is to go for Customization. I support Avijit's answer. Otherwise wait for some other experts to chime in